# How to access available fields of @metadata in logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat

A sample logstash is running and getting input data from a filebeat running on another machine in the same network. I need to process some metadata of files forwarded by filebeat for example `modified date` of input file. I found that this information may be available in @metadata variable, and can access some fields like this:

```
  %{[@metadata][type]}
  %{[@metadata][beat]}
```

but I don't know how to access all kind of data stored in this field so that i'll be able to extract my own data.

Comment: Filebeat doesn't send the file's modified date in the events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following configuration to your logstash.conf file:

```
output { 
   stdout { 
     codec  => rubydebug {
     metadata => true
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-metadata

But this field does not contain metadata of input file

Comment: You should give the answer here, not just a link, since links can easily become outdated.